# Multitouch image that plays sound after a certain sequence

Tags: android, multi-touch

I am confused how to start building an application like below.

`Scenario:` I have an image where two bells(bell-1,bell-2) hanging like `pendulum`.My purpose are-

1. If i sweep bell-1,it will go right side and back to left side(what a pendulum does) and makes sound.
2. If i sweep bell-2,it will do like bell-1.
3. If i sweep bell-1 and bell-2, both bells will go left to right to left (like pendulum) and makes sound.

My question is : **What is the best way to do an application like this which will support all android devices.**

Any help like document,links or advice will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinkg you have two major tasks.

1. create a pendulam
2. play multiple sounds

to create a pendulam you can see this [project](https://github.com/chiuki/android-pendulum-animation). To specify the animation from xml here is a key part

```
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:fromDegrees="15"
  android:toDegrees="-15"
  android:pivotX="50%"
  android:pivotY="0%"
  android:duration="2000"
  android:repeatMode="reverse"
  android:repeatCount="-1"/>
```

And to play multiple sounds use [SoundPool](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html). You can find plenty of examples out there.